# How do I change the background at boot time for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, gnome

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME. I want to replace the background image of the screen where I'm asked to choose between Windows and Ubuntu.

I replaced this image

```
/usr/share/images/desktop-grub/desktop-grub.png
```

with another image at the same location with the same name.

But now the screen has a blank background and does not display the new image.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to change the background image.

To install, open a terminal and enter the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Run Grub Customizer. Go to Appearance Settings > background image.

You should choose an image that will be available at boot time. So, I strongly recommend that you place the image of your choice in `/usr/share/images/` or `/usr/share/backgrounds` (you have, of course, already done that).

Comment: when i do

    "add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer"

i get this error.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (56, 'Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT')

Comment: That looks like a temporary error with the server (though I could be wrong). Please try again now that some hours have passed. Remember to use `sudo` in front of the command.